Alineación de secciones en el entorno multicols
estoy tratando hacer un documento de dos columnas en las que en cada columna deseo poner una sección.
El problema es que cuando uso columnbreak, la sección de la segunda columna aparece mucho más arriba que la de la primera y al parecer es por el texto, ya que en altura es menor que el primero.
¿Cómo podría alinearlos? ¡Gracias!

El código que hace esta parte es el siguiente:
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Área y Perímetro de Figuras \\Planas}
    \columnbreak
    \section{Perímetro y área de algunas\\ figuras planas}
\end{multicols}

